# Transparent WebView (with drawsBackground = false)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, monomac

I've got an example which has a transparent webview with some html controls in it. The WebView control is set to `drawsBackground` is false and it's on on a window which `isOpaque` is false and `backgroundColor` is Clear - which produces a completely transparent window with html controls.
The only problem is that the transparent area is not click through (My clicks are stopping on the webview).

Anyone knows if there's a way to make it "click through"?

Comment: Hi. Is there a reason you unaccepted my answer which you accepted a couple of days ago ??

Comment: Yes, cause you misunderstand. I want webview with transparent _page_ background. Not a transparent webView.

Comment: You do say " which has a transparent web view". Not sure why you accepted it in the first place if that was wrong. Can you post a Screen grab of what you have. Also it would help if you use the webView and NSWindow element class names. Can you do this to make it easier to understand what you mean. i.e what is page?. What are the controls –

Answer (score 2):

In a custom subclass of WebView you can implement:

```
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint;
```

to return nil if the user clicks on the transparent area.

Comment: That's ok, but how can I detect if the click is on top of webview content (like the letter "O") and detect if the click is inside the letter "O" for example?

Answer (score 2):

You question is a little bit confusing.

If you mean you want a Transparent window with a transparent webview overlaid with some controls/Buttons on top.  Which makes the  controls/Buttons appear floating and to be able to click through the unseen window and web view with the App losing focus and whatever you have clicked underneath becomes the active app.

If you mean the App stays Active but the click events act on anything below the transparent window. See @WilShipley 's  Answer.

An this example which I just tested and works.

1, In the AppDelegate's awakeFromNib  you set the webview's Alpha to 0.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Transparent
//
//  Created by Mark Hunte on 19/01/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Mark Hunte. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{

    [_theWebView  setAlphaValue:0];

}
@end
```

2, Subclass the NSWindow using:

`[self setOpaque:NO];`
`[self setHasShadow:NO];`

And styleMask of you choice along with any other options you want.

Here I gave it a Title bar.

*( 
If you do not want a title bar but want to move it around. You would have to override :
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow 
And use:
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
To track the window movement and location.
)*

**MyWindow.h**

```
    //
    //  MyWindow.h
    //
    //  Created by markhunte on 12/12/2010.
    //  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    @interface MyWindow: NSWindow {



    }
        - (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(unsigned int)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag;

@end
```

**MyWindow.m**

```
//
//  MyWindow.m
//
//  Created by markhunte on 12/12/2010.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyWindow.h"

@implementation MyWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(unsigned int)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag {

        self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
        if (self)
        {

            [self setOpaque:NO];
            [self setHasShadow:NO];
        }
        return self;

}

@end
```

3, Subclass the NSWindow's **View** using:

`[[NSColor clearColor] set];`

`NSRectFill([self frame]);`

in its `- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect`

**MyView.h**

```
//
//  MyView.h

//
//  Created by markhunte on 13/12/2010.
//  Copyright 2010 markosx.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface MyView : NSView{

}
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect;
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect;

@end
```

**MyView.m**

```
//
//  MyView.m

//
//  Created by markhunte on 13/12/2010.
//  Copyright 2010 markosx.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    return self;
}




- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{ 


         [[NSColor clearColor] set];
        NSRectFill([self frame]);


}

@end
```

---

In IB the Layout Connect the webview as a IBOutlet named here as **theWebView**

[image]

I have placed some labels in the layout just for illustration.

When Run the Window shows as:

[image]

---

And I can click through any part of the transparent window and webview to anything behind it.

---

I have added the source code to my blog [The Cocoa Quest](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/transparent-nswindow-using-subclasses-of-nswindow-and-nsview/)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to upload the source on dropbox or any storage service?

Comment: @blez (just noticed i put this comment on the other answer by mistake so have moved it here)I have change the link to the Source code on my Blog to:http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/transparent-nswindow-using-subclasses-of-nswindow-and-nsview/